# Have problem with if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES[‘file’][´tmp_name´]), when trying to update info if one of three images changed

Tags: php, html, mysql

Made a form to edit information, and if I want to change one of three images, errors comes up:

> Notice: Undefined index: file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/m-dev-store/admin_area/edit_product.php on line 345
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/m-dev-store/admin_area/edit_product.php on line 345

And even if I haven’t changed any images, just tried to change title for example, still the same

How can I fix it?

These errors is at the bottom of the included code on the line where: `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){`

```
 <?php

  if(isset($_GET['edit_product'])){

    $edit_id = $_GET['edit_product'];
    $get_p = "select * from products where product_id='$edit_id'";
    $run_edit = mysqli_query($con,$get_p);
    $row_edit = mysqli_fetch_array($run_edit);

    $p_id = $row_edit['product_id'];
    $p_title = $row_edit['product_title'];
    $p_cat = $row_edit['p_cat_id'];
    $cat= $row_edit['cat_id'];
    $manufacturer = $row_edit['manufacturer_id'];
    $p_image1 = $row_edit['product_img1'];
    $p_image2 = $row_edit['product_img2'];
    $p_image3 = $row_edit['product_img3'];
    $p_price = $row_edit['product_price'];
    $p_keywords = $row_edit['product_keywords'];
    $p_desc = $row_edit['product_desc'];

  }
  $get_manufacturer = "select * from manufacturers where manufacturer_id='$manufacturer'";
  $run_manufacturer = mysqli_query($con,$get_manufacturer);
  $row_manufacturer = mysqli_fetch_array($run_manufacturer);
  $manufacturer_title = $row_manufacturer['manufacturer_title'];

  $get_p_cat = "select * from product_categories where p_cat_id='$p_cat'";
  $run_p_cat = mysqli_query($con,$get_p_cat);
  $row_p_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_p_cat);
  $p_cat_title = $row_p_cat['p_cat_title'];

  $get_cat = "select * from categories where cat_id='$cat'";
  $run_cat = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat);
  $row_cat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat);
  $cat_title = $row_cat['cat_title'];




?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Insert Products </title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->

    <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->

        <ol class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->

            <li class="active"><!-- active Begin -->

                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard / Edit Product

            </li><!-- active Finish -->

        </ol><!-- breadcrumb Finish -->

    </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finish -->

</div><!-- row Finish -->

<div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->

    <div class="col-lg-12"><!-- col-lg-12 Begin -->

        <div class="panel panel-default"><!-- panel panel-default Begin -->

           <div class="panel-heading"><!-- panel-heading Begin -->

               <h3 class="panel-title"><!-- panel-title Begin -->

                   <i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i> Insert Product

               </h3><!-- panel-title Finish -->

           </div> <!-- panel-heading Finish -->

           <div class="panel-body"><!-- panel-body Begin -->

               <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- form-horizontal Begin -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Title </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_title" type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $p_title; ?>">

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Manufacturer </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <select name="manufacturer" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->

                              <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>"> <?php echo $manufacturer_title; ?> </option>

                              <?php

                              $get_manufacturer = "select * from manufacturers";
                              $run_manufacturer = mysqli_query($con,$get_manufacturer);

                              while ($row_manufacturer=mysqli_fetch_array($run_manufacturer)){

                                  $manufacturer_id = $row_manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];
                                  $manufacturer_title = $row_manufacturer['manufacturer_title'];

                                  echo "

                                  <option value='$manufacturer_id'> $manufacturer_title </option>

                                  ";

                              }

                              ?>

                          </select><!-- form-control Finish -->

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Category </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <select name="product_cat" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->

                              <option value="<?php echo $p_cat; ?>"> <?php echo $p_cat_title; ?> </option>

                              <?php

                              $get_p_cats = "select * from product_categories";
                              $run_p_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_p_cats);

                              while ($row_p_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_p_cats)){

                                  $p_cat_id = $row_p_cats['p_cat_id'];
                                  $p_cat_title = $row_p_cats['p_cat_title'];

                                  echo "

                                  <option value='$p_cat_id'> $p_cat_title </option>

                                  ";

                              }

                              ?>

                          </select><!-- form-control Finish -->

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Category </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <select name="cat" class="form-control"><!-- form-control Begin -->

                              <option value="<?php echo $cat; ?>"> <?php echo $cat_title; ?> </option>

                              <?php

                              $get_cat = "select * from categories";
                              $run_cat = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat);

                              while ($row_cat=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat)){

                                  $cat_id = $row_cat['cat_id'];
                                  $cat_title = $row_cat['cat_title'];

                                  echo "

                                  <option value='$cat_id'> $cat_title </option>

                                  ";

                              }

                              ?>

                          </select><!-- form-control Finish -->

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Image 1 </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_img1" type="file" class="form-control">
                          <br>
                          <img width="70" height="70" src="product_images/<?php echo $p_image1; ?>" alt="<?php echo $p_image1; ?>">

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Image 2 </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_img2" type="file" class="form-control">
                          <br>
                          <img width="70" height="70" src="product_images/<?php echo $p_image2; ?>" alt="<?php echo $p_image2; ?>">


                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Image 3 </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_img3" type="file" class="form-control form-height-custom">
                          <br>
                          <img width="70" height="70" src="product_images/<?php echo $p_image3; ?>" alt="<?php echo $p_image3; ?>">


                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Price </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_price" type="text" class="form-control" required value="$<?php echo $p_price; ?>">

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Keywords </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="product_keywords" type="text" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $p_keywords; ?>">

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"> Product Desc </label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <textarea name="product_desc" cols="19" rows="6" class="form-control">

                            <?php echo $p_desc; ?>

                          </textarea>

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

                   <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->

                      <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

                      <div class="col-md-6"><!-- col-md-6 Begin -->

                          <input name="update" value="Update Product" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">

                      </div><!-- col-md-6 Finish -->

                   </div><!-- form-group Finish -->

               </form><!-- form-horizontal Finish -->

           </div><!-- panel-body Finish -->

        </div><!-- canel panel-default Finish -->

    </div><!-- col-lg-12 Finish -->

</div><!-- row Finish -->

    <script src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea'});</script>
</body>
</html>


<?php

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];
    $manufacturer_id = $_POST['manufacturer'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){

        $product_img1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['name'];
        $product_img2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['name'];
        $product_img3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['name'];

        $temp_name1 = $_FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
        $temp_name2 = $_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
        $temp_name3 = $_FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

        move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,"product_images/$product_img1");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,"product_images/$product_img2");
        move_uploaded_file($temp_name3,"product_images/$product_img3");

        $update_product = "update products set p_cat_id='$product_cat', cat_id='$cat', manufacturer_id='$manufacturer_id',date=NOW(),product_title='$product_title', product_img1='$product_img1', product_img2='$product_img2', product_img3='$product_img3',product_keywords='$product_keywords',product_desc='$product_desc', product_price='$product_price' where product_id='$p_id'";
        $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$update_product);
        if($run_product){
          echo "<script>alert('Your Product Has Been Updated!')</script>";
          echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_products','_self')</script>";

        }

     }else{ 

        $update_product = "update products set p_cat_id='$product_cat', cat_id='$cat', manufacturer_id='$manufacturer_id',date=NOW(),product_title='$product_title', product_keywords='$product_keywords',product_desc='$product_desc', product_price='$product_price' where product_id='$p_id'";
        $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$update_product);

        if($run_product){
          echo "<script>alert('Your Product Has Been Updated!')</script>";
          echo "<script>window.open('index.php?view_products','_self')</script>";

        }

    }


}

?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

firstly `Undefined index` means that the entry was not found in the array.
As I can see you have 3 elements to select files.

```
<input name="product_img2" type="file" class="form-control">
```

and

```
<input name="product_img2" type="file" class="form-control">
```

amd

```
<input name="product_img3" type="file" class="form-control form-height-custom">
```

but you're taking `['file']['tmp_name']`
in this array you need to take the name of that file element which you're trying to post or get.
so if you want to upload file from this

```
<input name="product_img2" type="file" class="form-control">
```

then you need to take its name `product_img2` in the files array
example:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'])){
```

you can change it according to your page

Comment: But what if i want to change one of these three inputs?

Comment: you need to make another variables, as per your question `Undefined index` I answered that, `Undefined index` mean that the entry was not found in the array.

Comment: can you show what exactly in the code i have to edit?

Comment: as you already wrote that `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){` refers to line number 345. Than you need to put the `name` of the file element which you're trying to check if uploaded. Example: `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){` if your `file` element is `product_img2` then write `product_img2` instead of `file` in `['file']`, it should be `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'])){
`

Comment: not working. "if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){ " by this line i am trying to refer to inputs that are of type 'file' and if there uploaded a new file, then to upload them. But its not working, and seems there other issue

Comment: @Rohit Sahu OP can use if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'])){

Comment: "by this line i am trying to refer to inputs that are of type 'file'". That's not how it works. The index refers to the **name** of the input, not it's type. Exactly the same as with the $_POST array. Test with `var_dump($_FILES);` and you'll see what I (and Kumar) am saying.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `where product_id='$edit_id'`  not `where product_id='$p_id'`

```
 $update_product = "update products set p_cat_id='$product_cat', cat_id='$cat', manufacturer_id='$manufacturer_id',date=NOW(),product_title='$product_title', product_keywords='$product_keywords',product_desc='$product_desc', product_price='$product_price' where product_id='$edit_id'";
            $run_product = mysqli_query($con,$update_product);
```

Comment: no, its not working.

Comment: remove  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){  this line of code.

Comment: explain please more explicitly. What exactly do i have to change in the code?